# API call troubleshoot / using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using this country API: https://countryapi.io/documentation, and I am creating a form where you submit the name of the country. Ex, you type Spain, and the call is completed and gives you the capital "Madrid".

In Javascript,

I have my variables

```
const url = "https://countryapi.io/"
const apiKey = "x"
```

My function to requestCountry

```
function requestCountry(countryName){

const requestUrl = `${url}api/all?apikey=${apiKey}/name/${countryName}    

    fetch(requestUrl)
    .then((res) => {return res.json()})
    .then((data) => {
        displayCountry(data)
})

}


requestCountry("spain")
```

My trouble is the variable requestUrl, and how it access the API. When reading the documentation, specifically endpoint by name it say "GET [https://countryapi.io/api/name/austria"](https://countryapi.io/api/name/austria%22).
Which means clearly my requestUrl is incorrect, and I can see that. However, I don't know exactly know how I should be calling this. I am confused by both the GET in that, and how it doesn't reference the APIKey. Am I having to input, https://countryapi.io/api/all?apikey=YOUR-APIKEY , and then I need to make a secondary request with the , GET https://countryapi.io/api/name/spain , to get spain? Thank you!

I've mainly tried changing the const requestUrl. I try "/", "", "=", and then changed the order around. I've had name/${countryName}, after https://countryapi.io/api, and all over the place

Comment: No, you need to include your API key with all your requests. The `api/all` example is just showing you do that. `api/all`is just an endpoint chosen for purposes of that example; scroll down to the "Endpoint for all countries" bit for details of what it does. Pick the endpoint relevant to your use case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is secondary to your question, but looks like you have a syntax error. The syntax highlighting is a dead giveaway.

Comment: And `GET` just means you make a `GET` call, which is fetch()'s default. Other possible request types include things like `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending `?apikey=${apiKey}` at the END of the URL instead of, you know, **in the middle**.

E.g.

```
https://countryapi.io/api/all?apikey=YOUR-APIKEY
https://countryapi.io/api/name/austria?apikey=YOUR-APIKEY
```

Everything after the `?` is usually considered a *URL parameter* (I could direct you to a long RFC on the subject, but I won't).

URL parameters most often take the form of `?foo=qux&bar=quux` where `foo` and `bar` are the names of the parameters which get the values "qux" and "quux" respectively.

Comment: This is what I have currently

```
const requestUrl = `${url}api/name/${countryName}?apikey=${apiKey}`
```
It is calling but giving me back undefined. My assumption would be my 

```requestCountry("spain")```

Is not correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but that's *not* what you have in the code you posted.

Comment: [What does the debugger say](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) `requestUrl` is set to at that point right after you assign it? What does the network trace say is returned by the server? Any errors on the console?

Comment: Sorry, I should of said, I changed it to the recommendation you provided above

Comment: So if I

`console.log(data)`, I do save the object of spain. I'm getting closer. Your recommendation did work. I have the object in my console now. I believe I am creating a problem in a different function now, which is supposed to take the input of the original function above

Comment: @Flix "*I am creating a problem in a different function now, which is supposed to take the input of the original function above*" - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572 for that. Your function does not currently `return` anything, and when it does, all it can return is a promise which the caller still will need to wait for.